# python manage.py syncdb error

Tags: python, mysql, django, syncdb

I am attempting to get my first Django project working, on Windows, but I get an error message that reads:

```
File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-pazcre\MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-    win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__     mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'django_user'@'localhost'     (using password: YES)")
```

I created my database from the command line as:

```
-- create the database
CREATE DATABASE GlobalXdb CHARACTER SET utf8;

-- create user
CREATE USER 'django_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';

-- give user permissions to db 
GRANT ALL ON django.* TO 'django_user'@'localhost'
```

My `settings.py` file contains:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'GlobalXdb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'django_user',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'thepassword',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

}

Can anyone shed some light on what I have done incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database is named **GlobalXdb** and yet in this line...

```
#give user permissions to db 
GRANT ALL ON django.* TO 'django_user'@'localhost'
```

you grant permissions to django_user on database named **django**.

Give permissions to the correct database **GlobalXdb** should solve your problem.

Comment: Django allows you to define multiple database access permissions for a database.  You can then specify the database access you want to use when running syncd db.  See me answer below....

Answer (score 2):

The error message says `Access denied for user 'django_user'@'localhost'` so my guess would be that the user 'django_user' doesn't exist or you typed the password wrong.

Another less likely suggestion would be to check the rights granted for 'django_user'. It's possible that this user doesn't have permission to create tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by defining two DATABASE profiles in your *settings.py*.

**default** - Used by django at runtime with **limited permissions** for that extra security.

**sync** - Used by syncdb, as user **root**, with extra create privileges.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':'database_name',
    'USER':'runtime',
    'PASSWORD':'runtime_password',
    'HOST':'',
    'PORT':'',
  },
  'sync': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':'database_name',
    'USER':'root',
    'PASSWORD':'',
    'HOST':'',
    'PORT':'',
  },
}
```

You will also have to grant **limited permissions** for the default runtime access in MySQL:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database_name.* TO 'runtime'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'runtime_password';
```

Finally when you run *syncdb* specify your **sync** access profile:

```
python manage.py syncdb --database=sync
```

That should give you the security you want at runtime and the access you want on the command line.